# Formatar sequencia numérica em formato CPF com separadores usando javascript

Tags: javascript

A função abaixo testa a entrada de um cpf, (digitando ou **colando**) cujo formato deve ser `###.###.###-##`

Caso a entrada seja constituída somente de números sem os separadores, ou faltando algum separador, como por exemplo  `###.########` como posso fazer para que o  `value` do input seja convertido para o formato válido.

> não é validação de CPF e sim formatação pura!!!

```js
function ValidaCPF(){   

    var ao_cpf=document.forms.form1.ao_cpf.value; 
    var cpfValido = /^(([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}))$/;     
    if (cpfValido.test(ao_cpf) == false)    {  
       //alert("invalido");
       var valorValido = document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value = "???????";
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="ao_cpf" id="ao_cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnBlur="ValidaCPF();"/>
</form>
```

> vou exemplificar com números para ficar claro

- ao entrar `11111111111` me retorne no input `111.111.111-11`
- ao entrar `111.11111111` me retorne no input `111.111.111-11`
- ao entrar `111.111111-11` me retorne no input `111.111.111-11`
- etc...

Comment: você quer validar a quantidade de numeros tbm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Devido ao comentário do @Everson

`Este código da resposta funciona, porém, se não está na formatação exata de 11 dígitos não vai funcionar mesmo`

na resposta do @J. Guilherme consegui fazer que o código funcionasse a contento.

```js
function ValidaCPF(){   

var ao_cpf=document.forms.form1.ao_cpf.value; 
var cpfValido = /^(([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}))$/;     
if (cpfValido.test(ao_cpf) == false)    { 
     
   ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /\D/g , ""); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
      
   if (ao_cpf.length==11){
   ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
   ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
   //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
   ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/ , "$1-$2"); //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
       
   var valorValido = document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value = ao_cpf;
 }else{
   console.log("CPF invalido");
 }
  
}
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="ao_cpf" id="ao_cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnBlur="ValidaCPF();"/>
</form>
```

> o X da questão passa pela exclusão de qualquer digito que não seja numero e testar se retorna 11 caracteres, o que supõe que foi inserido um cpf valido porém sem a formatação esperada.

```js
function ValidaCPF(){   
  var ao_cpf=document.forms.form1.ao_cpf.value; 
  var cpfValido = /^(([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}))$/;     
  ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
  ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
  //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
  ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/ , "$1-$2"); //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
       
  var valorValido = document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value = ao_cpf;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="ao_cpf" id="ao_cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnBlur="ValidaCPF();"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 25):

Venho usando regex para fazer esse tipo de formatação há algum tempo e tem me atendido bem.

```
var cpf = "00000000000";

console.log(formataCPF(cpf));

function formataCPF(cpf){
  //retira os caracteres indesejados...
  cpf = cpf.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  
  //realizar a formatação...
    return cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
}
```

Preparei uma proposta de solução no jsfiddle.
Segue o link: https://jsfiddle.net/hye31ufr/1/

Comment: simples e funciona muito bem! obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Edite sua função da seguinte forma:

```js
function ValidaCPF(){   

    var ao_cpf=document.forms.form1.ao_cpf.value; 
    if(ao_cpf.match(/\d/g).join('').length === 11) { 
        console.log('cpf invalido.'); 
        return;
    }
    var cpfValido = /^(([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}))$/;     
    if (cpfValido.test(ao_cpf) == false)    {  
       //alert("invalido");
       var formattedCpf = ao_cpf.replace(/^(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{2})$/g,'$1.$2.$3-$4');
       var valorValido = document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value = formattedCpf;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="ao_cpf" id="ao_cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnBlur="ValidaCPF();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Alguem poderia me explicar por quê minha resposta foi negativada?

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei,o ideal seria você postar uma resposta completa e/ou executável.

Comment: eu editei meu post de forma a deixar mais claro a função

Comment: Pois é, lendo o código parece tudo certo e que deveria funcionar  mas como as demais, que também parecem corretas, que andei experimentando, não dá retorno

Comment: Este código da resposta [funciona](https://jsfiddle.net/9k7t13bc/), porém, se não está na formatação exata de 11 dígitos não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: @Everson exato, se limitar o input a 11 dígitos vai dar problema ao digitar o cpf correto manualmente

Comment: @Everson, essa sua observação acendeu as lamparinas do meu cérebro e me levou a resposta da  minha pergunta!!!!!!

Comment: eu tava em dúvida se tinha que validar o tamanho do número, por isso perguntei nos comments da pergunta... mas que bom que no fim deu certo! ps: editei minha resposta validando o tamanho do tbm, pra deixar completa

Answer (score 1):

Pequena melhoria no exemplo com regex com tolerância a `nulos` ou `undefined`

```js
function formatCpf(text) {
    const badchars = /[^\d]/g
    const mask = /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/
    const cpf = new String(text).replace(badchars, "");
    return cpf.replace(mask, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz esse script para mim, e deu certo.
Só lembrando, nesse caso o input estava com o atributo maxlength valor 15.

```
document.getElementById('CPF').value = "___.___.___-__";
function validateCPF(){
var CPF = document.getElementById('CPF').value;
var auxCPF = true;
var cpf = [];
for (var i = 0; i < CPF.length; i++) {
    cpf.push(CPF[i]);
    if(i != 3 && i != 7 && i != 11){
        if (CPF[i] != '0' && CPF[i] != '1' && CPF[i] != '2' && CPF[i] != '3' && CPF[i] != '4' && CPF[i] != '5' && CPF[i] != '6' && CPF[i] != '7' && CPF[i] != '8' && CPF[i] != '9' && CPF != "___.___.___-_") {
            auxCPF = false;
            cpf.splice(i, 1,);
        }else if(auxCPF == true){
            auxCPF == true;
            s_CPF.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
    if(cpf.length < CPF.length){
        if(i == 2 && CPF[3] != "."){
            cpf.splice(3, 0, ".");
            console.log(cpf);
        }
        if(i == 6 && CPF[7] != "."){
            cpf.splice(7, 0, ".");
            console.log(cpf);
        }
        if(i == 10 && CPF[11] != "-"){
            cpf.splice(11, 0, "-");
            console.log(cpf);
        }
    }
}
lastCPF = "";
for (var i = 0; i < cpf.length; i++) {
    if((cpf[i] == "." && i != 3 && i != 7) || (cpf[i] == "-" && i != 11) || cpf[i] == "_" || cpf[i] == " "  || i < 14 && (i != 11 && i != 3 && i != 7 && cpf[i] != '0' && cpf[i] != '1' && cpf[i] != '2' && cpf[i] != '3' && cpf[i] != '4' && cpf[i] != '5' && cpf[i] != '6' && cpf[i] != '7' && cpf[i] != '8' && cpf[i] != '9') || i > 13){
        cpf.splice(i,1,"");
        console.log(cpf);
    }
    lastCPF += cpf[i];
}
document.getElementById('CPF').value = lastCPF;
if(document.getElementById('CPF').value == ""){
    document.getElementById('CPF').value = "___.___.___-__";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz dessa forma, caso você esteja recebendo o cpf como inteiro (pode acontecer) o método toString() não vai deixar quebrar sua função, é mais uma garantia mesmo, depois faça o slice do cpf inserindo os pontos e - no final.

```
     const formatCpf = (cpf) => {
    cpf = cpf.toString()
    return cpf.slice(0,3) + "." + cpf.slice(3,6) + "." + cpf.slice(6,9) + "-" + cpf.slice(9,11)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"Tenta isso"

```js
function cpfCnpj(v,label){

    //CNPJ
    if (label == 'J'){
        return formataCampo(v, '00.000.000/0000-00', event);
    }
    //CPF
    if (label == 'F'){
        return formataCampo(v, '000.000.000-00', event);
    }

}
//formata de forma generica os campos
function formataCampo(campo, Mascara, evento) { 
    var boleanoMascara; 

    var Digitato = evento.keyCode;
    exp = /\-|\.|\/|\(|\)| /g
    campoSoNumeros = campo.value.toString().replace( exp, "" ); 

    var posicaoCampo = 0;     
    var NovoValorCampo="";
    var TamanhoMascara = campoSoNumeros.length;; 

    if (Digitato != 8) { // backspace 
        for(i=0; i<= TamanhoMascara; i++) { 
            boleanoMascara  = ((Mascara.charAt(i) == "-") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ".")
                                || (Mascara.charAt(i) == "/")) 
            boleanoMascara  = boleanoMascara || ((Mascara.charAt(i) == "(") 
                                || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ")") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == " ")) 
            if (boleanoMascara) { 
                NovoValorCampo += Mascara.charAt(i); 
                  TamanhoMascara++;
            }else { 
                NovoValorCampo += campoSoNumeros.charAt(posicaoCampo); 
                posicaoCampo++; 
              }            
          }     
        campo.value = NovoValorCampo;
          return true; 
    }else { 
        return true; 
    }
}

//Ou ainda em Jquery

$(function($){
   $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
   $("#cnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
});
```

Comment: olha a tag, javascript

Comment: me esqueci ! desculpa ajudou ?

Comment: valeu o esforço, mas gostaria de passar para a variavel valorValido o formato valido dentro daquela função