# Expressões Regulares com Javascript (MASCARA DE CPF)

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar uma máscara de cpf em javascript porém o meu código não é aplicado no input, porém quando eu dou um console.log() no código está sendo aplicado no console.

---

*Meu input:*

```
<input id="cpf" onblur="codigo.colocaMascara()" type="text" class="form-control" required />
```

*Código Javascript:*

```js
    class Codigo {
         colocaMascara() {
    
            let cpf = document.querySelector('#cpf');
    
            cpf.addEventListener('input', (text) => {
    
                let resultado = text.target.value;
                
                return resultado
                    .replace(/\D/g, '')
                    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
                    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
                    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1-$2')
                    .replace(/(\-d{2})\d+?$/, '$1')
                
            });
            
     
        }
    }
```

```html
<input id="cpf" onblur="codigo.colocaMascara()" type="text" class="form-control" required />
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218989/formatar-sequencia-num%C3%A9rica-em-formato-cpf-com-separadores-usando-javascript

Comment: <input id="cpf" onkeyup="codigo.colocaMascara()" type="text" class="form-control" required />

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatar sequencia numérica em formato CPF com separadores usando javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218989/formatar-sequencia-num%c3%a9rica-em-formato-cpf-com-separadores-usando-javascript)

Comment: Já dei uma olhada nesses aí, mas é que eu queria saber o que tem de errado no meu código. Tipo só não está mostrando no input.

Comment: Você está dando return no resultado e não atribuindo ao value do input

Comment: `codigo is not defined`; você definiu a classe `Codigo`, mas em nenhum momento você a instanciou criando o objeto `codigo` que utilizou no `<input>`.

Comment: Complementando o que @Woss comentou... Se sua classe só tem isso, não precisa dela, seria mais simples ter apenas o objeto (criando com `const codigo = { colocaMascara: () => { /* ... */}}`). Se for manter a classe seria interessante a variável `cpf` fora do método, assim é acessível por todos os métodos e o `querySelector` não será chamado todo o tempo, pode ainda receber essa referência ao elemento HTML no construtor, fazendo uma inversão de controle e desacoplando seu código

Comment: é, eu instanciei a classe sim, só esqueci de colocar aqui. Mas obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns problemas de execução, o mais grave é não atribuir o valor para o campo, somente um return não vai alterar o valor, por isso coloquei `cpf.value = resultado`, o segundo é relacionado aos eventos, só funciona se der um clique dentro e outro fora do campo, daí ele ativa o `blur`. A forma como você invoca a classe também está errada, para instanciar é necessário o uso do `new` e dos `()` para construção.

Fiz dessa forma:

```js
class Codigo {
     colocaMascara() {

        let cpf = document.querySelector('#cpf');

        cpf.addEventListener('input', (text) => {

            let resultado = text.target.value;

            cpf.value = resultado
                .replace(/\D/g, '')
                .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
                .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
                .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1-$2')
                .replace(/(\-d{2})\d+?$/, '$1')
        });
    }
}

new Codigo().colocaMascara()
```

```html
    <input id="cpf" type="text" class="form-control" required />
```

Você pode remover também a classe, deixando apenas uma função:

```js
let cpf = document.querySelector('#cpf');
function colocaMascara(event) {
    let resultado = event.target.value;

    cpf.value = resultado
        .replace(/\D/g, '')
        .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
        .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
        .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1-$2')
        .replace(/(\-d{2})\d+?$/, '$1')
}
```

```html
<input id="cpf" type="text" oninput="colocaMascara(event)" class="form-control" required />
```

Obs.: Coloquei a atribuição da variável `cpf` fora da função com base no comentário do @Costamilam, dessa forma só é chamado uma única vez

Comment: Sobre transformar em uma função, é que eu estou em um escopo maior no projeto, eu tenho mais métodos na classe(tipo pra validar o cpf) ai eu criei a classe pra fazer todas as manipulações do cpf ou outros dados. Obrigado pela sua resposta, funcionou aqui. Só a minha última expressão regular que não está regulando o tamanho do input, mas devo ter errado em algo.

Comment: Eu achei que a variavel resultado já estava pegando o value do input, mas aparentemente o text passado como parâmetro não é o value do meu input? Depois que eu coloco text.target.value

Comment: E quanto ao evento que você usou no botão: oninput, dá na mesma colocar onkeyup ou onkeypress, né?

Comment: Isso, tem o mesmo valor do value, mas não sei se funciona atribuir nele mesmo, creio que não, também funciona se você usar esses outros 2 eventos

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.